# I'm getting SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new on Hibernate. I'm trying to implement **OneToMany** and **ManyToOne** mapping while doing i stuck and SQLGrammarException.

This is Category (pojo) class.

```
package com.app.pojos;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

//Category class will have all master categories like Adventurous, tourist destinations etc.
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {
    private Integer cid;
    private String name,image,desc;
    private List<SubCategory> subcategories = new ArrayList<>();

    public Category() {

    }

    public Category(String name, String image, String desc, List<SubCategory> subcategories) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }

    public Category(Integer cid, String name, String image, String desc, List<SubCategory> subcategories) {
        super();
        this.cid = cid;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getCid() {
        return cid;
    }

    public void setCid(Integer cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    //This is category name
    @NotBlank(message="Name is REQUIRED....")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //This is category image to be displayed
    @NotBlank(message="Please select an image....")
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


    @NotBlank(message="desc is REQUIRED....")
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    //This is an INVERSE SIDE because it is not having foreign key......
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=SubCategory.class,mappedBy="category",
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<SubCategory> getSubcategories() {
        return subcategories;
    }


    public void setSubcategories(List<SubCategory> subcategories) {
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }

    //Convenience method sub-category into  category
    public void addSubCategory(SubCategory sub) {
        subcategories.add(sub);
        sub.setCategory(this);
    }
}
```

This is my SubCategory(Pojo class) Class.

```
package com.app.pojos;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="subcategory")
public class SubCategory {
    private Integer scid;
    private String name,image,desc;
    private Category category;

    public SubCategory() {

    }

    public SubCategory(String name, String image, String desc, Category category) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public SubCategory(Integer scid, String name, String image, String desc, Category category) {
        super();
        this.scid = scid;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getScid() {
        return scid;
    }

    public void setScid(Integer scid) {
        this.scid = scid;
    }

    @NotBlank(message="Name is REQUIRED")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @NotBlank(message="Please select an image")
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @NotBlank(message="Desc is REQUIRED")
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }


    //This is the OWNING SIDE because it is having foreign key.....
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cat_id")
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


}
```

This is my main method.

```
package com.app.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

import com.app.dao.CategoryDao;
import com.app.pojos.Category;
import com.app.pojos.SubCategory;

import static utils.HibernateUtils.*;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            getSf();
            System.out.println("Enter Category details.....Name,image,desc");
            Category category  = new Category();
            category.setName(sc.nextLine());
            category.setImage(sc.nextLine());
            category.setDesc(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Enter sub category....Name,Image,desc");
            SubCategory sub = new SubCategory();
            sub.setName(sc.nextLine());
            sub.setImage(sc.nextLine());
            sub.setDesc(sc.nextLine());
            category.addSubCategory(sub);
            System.out.println("ID  : "+ new CategoryDao().saveCatgory(category));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            getSf().close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is CategoryDao class.

```
package com.app.dao;

import org.hibernate.*;

import com.app.pojos.Category;
import static utils.HibernateUtils.*;

public class CategoryDao {
    public String saveCatgory(Category c) {
        Session hs = getSf().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = hs.beginTransaction();
        try {
            hs.save(c);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
        return "Course added with ID=" + c.getCid();
    }
}
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vov</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="com.app.pojos.Category"/>
        <mapping class="com.app.pojos.SubCategory"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

These are the exceptions, I'm getting. This is complete console

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate: 

    create table category (
       cid integer not null auto_increment,
        desc varchar(255) not null,
        image varchar(255) not null,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (cid)
    )
Hibernate: 

    create table subcategory (
       scid integer not null auto_increment,
        desc varchar(255) not null,
        image varchar(255) not null,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        cat_id integer,
        primary key (scid)
    )
Hibernate: 

    alter table subcategory 
       add constraint FK2umvqgly5rb2aqk8v273tk4o5 
       foreign key (cat_id) 
       references category (cid)
sf created!!!!!
Enter Category details.....Name,image,desc
hlkj
khjlgfh
hgvnb
Enter sub category....Name,Image,desc
hjgctg
gcnb
hcgv
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        category
        (desc, image, name) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2907)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3478)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:355)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.dao.CategoryDao.saveCatgory(CategoryDao.java:13)
    at com.app.test.Tester.main(Tester.java:26)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, image, name) values ('hgvnb', 'khjlgfh', 'hlkj')' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: But your problem is at the 'desc' column name as a keyword

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos that's incorrect. In a bidirectional OneToMany, mappedBy must be on the one side.

Comment: If you have 1Category-NSubCategory  then the mapped by can be on subcategory since it will map it as a FK and will not use a aux_table, but bidirectional is impossible.

Comment: Pro tips: (1) block formatting of code does not need backticks here, please do not add them, unless you want inline formatting. Use the code formatting tool instead. (2) always use the preview window and proof-read your question completely before posting. (3) refrain from adding "please help me" messages, especially in the title. People know you want help, and messages of this kind are often understood by native English speakers as a form of begging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`desc` is a SQL keyword. Don't use that as a column name. `description` is much clearer anyway.